# How to force command line VLC to stream youtube videos of specific quality?

Tags: command-line, video, vlc, youtube, streaming

I want to stream youtube videos from command line using VLC media player. I was able to stream youtube videos using this command

```
cvlc https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2Oo4kBHBNU
```

The problem is that when ever VLC streams videos it uses highest quality video format available (480 and higher). I dont have a uniform interned download speed, some times I can play youtube video of 360 (my highest quality) and other times I can play a youtube video of 240 only.

Because VLC currently streams with highest quality (480 and above according to video) I cant stream using `cvlc https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2Oo4kBHBNU` this command. How should I force commandline VLC to play video of specific quality?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the required *input* video settings in VLC for your YouTube clip in either of two ways:

1. *Locally* using the command line
2. *Globally* using the GUI

Details of both options below:

1. **Altering input video *locally* using the command-line:**

   You can request a specific video size from youtube from the commandline by using the `--preferred-resolution` option. This has the bonus of *not changing vlc global settings*, so settings specified in this manner are not saved. Settings for this are (seen in `cvlc -h`):

   1. **-1** (The *default*, this selects best available video quality)
   2. **1080** (This selects Full HD: 1080p)
   3. **720** (This selects HD: 720p)
   4. **576** (This selects Standard Definition: 576 or 480 lines)
   5. **360** (This selects Low Definition: 360 lines)
   6. **240** (This selects Very Low Definition: 240 lines)

   So for your clip the following works nicely:

   ```
   cvlc --preferred-resolution 240 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2Oo4kBHBNU
   ```
2. **Altering input video *globally* using the GUI:**

   You can also alter the input video settings *globally* from the GUI preferences as shown in the screenshot below:

   [image: screenshot]

   These settings are saved for subsequent vlc usage and will be saved in your vlc configuration file: `~/.config/vlc/vlcrc`. As an example: this is added for a preferred resolution of 240:

   ```
   # Preferred video resolution (integer)
   preferred-resolution=240
   ```

You have to love vlc :)

Comment: Thanks it worked but if we can change the resolution using command line itself would have been better

Comment: OIC: `cvlc --preferred-resolution 240 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2Oo4kBHBNU` is what you are after, I will add this in....

Comment: Please add this code to the answer  itself ; once more thank you very much :)

Comment: OK it is added an some extra information as a bonus :). And have a great day!

Comment: And you can list available resolutions with `-F` or `--list-formats`: `youtube-dl --list-formats https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2Oo4kBHBNU`.